# How to return values from pallets?

Tags: pallet

This sounds to me like a silly question - but how do I actually return something from a pallet call?

e.g. in the most basic example:

```rs
#[pallet::weight(0)]
pub fn get_answer_to_everything(_origin: OriginFor<T>) -> DispatchResult {
    Ok(42)
}
```

In my concrete example I have something like this:

```rs
#[pallet::storage]
pub(super) type Names<T: Config> = StorageMap<
    _,
    Blake2_128Concat,
    BoundedVec<u8, T::MaxLength>,
    (BoundedVec<u8, T::MaxLength>, T::AccountId)
>;
```

and I want to have a custom getter because polkadot.js seems to not play nicely with boundedvec and i want to have something like:

```rs
#[pallet::weight(0)]
pub fn get_name(_origin: OriginFor<T>, name_id: Vec<u8>) -> DispatchResult {
  let bounded_name_id: BoundedVec<_, _> = name_id.try_into().map_err(|_| Error::<T>::NameIdInvalidLengthTooLong)?;
  ensure!(<Names<T>>::contains_key(&bounded_name_id), Error::<T>::NameDoesNotExist);

  // return <Names<T>>::get(bounded_name_id) here
  Ok(())
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. And that's not a good idea.

You are making a query into an extrinsic. This means it will cost a fee when you query some storage. (if possible)

It is impossible to return a value from the pallet call.

But if you want a getter of the storage.

Add `#[pallet::getter(fn name)]` above the `Names`. Then, you get a rpc method `name`. You could find that in PolkadotApps - ChainState - Pallet - name.

But if you complain about the `BoundedVec` display style in PolkadotApps, try the following things.

---

Maybe you should wrap `BoundedVec` with a struct and add a special decoding method on JS side. I'm not sure about this. It's another question.

---

Or make a custom RPC method like pallet-transaction-payment or others, but I think this makes things complicated.

Comment: I can't really follow. Isn't the "getter" that I can add to the storage doing the same? I'm coming from solidity, where this is also common practise to discover the storage - what is the equivalent pattern in substrate?

How would I wrap BoundedVec with a struct and why is it better to give a struct back while giving back primitives is a bad idea?

Comment: Because the way you are trying to do is defining an extrinsic call. Add `#[pallet::getter(fn names)]` above the `Names` is the default way to add a getter to that storage.

Comment: Ok, so extrinsic calls should only be read only under all circumstances? So discovery of the storage may only be done by the default auto-generated getters? Is that correct to say?

Comment: The extrinsic call is similar to the transaction call in Ethereum. Users pay fee and execute the functions. The default auto-generated getter is something read-only, it queries the storage and returns the result to you. There are other ways to do that, like define a custom RPC query. It's what I said in the last part. We usually use that for more complicated situation. For example, get the names and check if it is CAPITAL if yes then return `Some(names)` else `None`. When you want a processed value, then use custom RPC.

Comment: Thanks. More questions to come :-)

Comment: Could you give me a hint where to look for wrapping with a struct?

Comment: `struct H256([u8; 32]);`, it is `[u8; 32]` actually. But PolkadotApps could recognize it as `Hash`, `0x..` instead of `[0, ..]`.

Comment: Ok, i am far away from understanding what you are talking about :-) - is there documentation around this?

Comment: Ah, I know found how i can query it on polkadot.js.org at least.